# Cannot write a text message in Text File using WP7

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, text-files, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I cannot write a file in a textfile in my wp7 application, what should I do?

here is my code

```
 Dim isolatedStorage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication
 Dim isoStream As IsolatedStorageFileStream = New IsolatedStorageFileStream("TextFile1.txt", FileMode.Append, isolatedStorage)
 Dim streamwriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(isoStream)

 streamwriter.WriteLine("sample")
 streamwriter.Close()
```

I also try to put it inside the Using statement, but it is still now writing in the text file

```
Dim isolatedStorage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication
        Using isoStream As IsolatedStorageFileStream = New IsolatedStorageFileStream("/TextFile1.txt", FileMode.Append, isolatedStorage)

            Using streamwriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(isoStream)
                streamwriter.WriteLine("PreMenu.xaml")

                streamwriter.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
```

there is no error, but it is not writing a text in textfile, what should I do?

Comment: How are you detecting that it's not writing? (You should use `Using` statements instead of explicitly closing, by the way.)

Comment: when I am opening the text file, the text file is blank.

Comment: it is still not working even though I put a using statement in my code.. :(

Comment: Please show the code which opens the text file then. And note that now you're using `Using` statements, you don't need to call `Close`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried this
 Using wf = isolatedStorage.OpenFile("TextFile1.txt", FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileMode.Append)

and this is the error

Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

Comment: That doesn't sound like "the text file is blank". Why are you opening it for read and write access if you're just trying to read from it?

Comment: I just put that, creating an experiment, but when I removed "FileAccess.ReadWrite" it is not producing error, but it is not the text file is still blank,what do you think is the problem?

Comment: Please edit the question with exactly what you tried, and how you established that it was empty.